# CS50 -pset4 filter (more comfortable) Edges - output image is so odd

Tags: c, cs50, edge-detection

I have been trying to do the Edge function in CS50 Problem Set 4.

I know people will set a 2-dimension array of Gx and Gy to loop through.

However, I am not smart enough to think of that initially.
So I just simply create some Gx/Gy variables so the when the pixel is loop through, the (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2) will be multiplied.

I know my method is definitely not ideal. It is too lengthy.

When I complied the function, the output image is wrong.

So just wondering can anyone give me some help please? Much appreciated.

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //copy the image into temp image by nested loop
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    int tempr[height][width];
    int tempg[height][width];
    int tempb[height][width];

    int temp_gxr[height][width];
    int temp_gxg[height][width];
    int temp_gxb[height][width];

    int temp_gyr[height][width];
    int temp_gyg[height][width];
    int temp_gyb[height][width];

    // For GX
    //loop through every pixel again
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int sum_gx_r = 0;
            int sum_gx_g = 0;
            int sum_gx_b = 0;
            for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
            {
                // for gx top and bottom row which is -1, 0, 1
                // for gx mid tow. which is -2, 0, 2
                int gx_top_bot = -1;
                int gx_mid = -2;
                for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++)
                {
                    int gx_x = i + x;
                    int gx_y = j + y;
                    // Skip corner cases
                    if ((gx_x < 0) || (gx_x > height - 1) || (gx_y < 0) || (gx_y > width - 1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // if row is top or bottom, * -1, 0, 1
                    if (x == -1 || x == 1)
                    {
                        sum_gx_r = sum_gx_r + image[gx_x][gx_y].rgbtRed *gx_top_bot;
                        sum_gx_g = sum_gx_g + image[gx_x][gx_y].rgbtGreen *gx_top_bot;
                        sum_gx_b = sum_gx_b + image[gx_x][gx_y].rgbtBlue *gx_top_bot;
                        gx_top_bot = gx_top_bot + 1;
                    }
                    // if row is mid, * -2, 0, 2
                    if (x == 0)
                    {
                        sum_gx_r = sum_gx_r + image[gx_x][gx_y].rgbtRed *gx_mid;
                        sum_gx_g = sum_gx_g + image[gx_x][gx_y].rgbtGreen *gx_mid;
                        sum_gx_b = sum_gx_b + image[gx_x][gx_y].rgbtBlue *gx_mid;
                        gx_mid = gx_mid + 2;
                    }
                }
            }
            temp_gxr[i][j] = sum_gx_r;
            temp_gxg[i][j] = sum_gx_g;
            temp_gxb[i][j] = sum_gx_b;
        }
    }

    // For Gy
    // Loop through all pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int sum_gy_r = 0;
            int sum_gy_g = 0;
            int sum_gy_b = 0;
            // for gy first and last row which is -1, 0, 1
            // for gy mid column which is -2, 0, 2
            int gy_left_right = -1;
            int gy_mid = -2;
            for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
            {

                for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++)
                {
                    int gy_x = i + x;
                    int gy_y = j + y;
                    // Skip corner cases
                    if ((gy_x < 0) || (gy_x > height - 1) || (gy_y < 0) || (gy_y > width - 1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // if left or right col, * -1 , 0, 1
                    if (y == -1 || y == 1)
                    {
                        sum_gy_r = sum_gy_r + image[gy_x][gy_y].rgbtRed *gy_left_right;
                        sum_gy_g = sum_gy_g + image[gy_x][gy_y].rgbtGreen *gy_left_right;
                        sum_gy_b = sum_gy_b + image[gy_x][gy_y].rgbtBlue *gy_left_right;
                    }
                    if (y == 0)
                    // if mid col, * -2 , 0, 2
                    {
                        sum_gy_r = sum_gy_r + image[gy_x][gy_y].rgbtRed *gy_mid;
                        sum_gy_g = sum_gy_g + image[gy_x][gy_y].rgbtGreen *gy_mid;
                        sum_gy_b = sum_gy_b + image[gy_x][gy_y].rgbtBlue *gy_mid;
                    }
                }
                gy_left_right = gy_left_right +1;
                gy_mid = gy_mid +2;
            }
            temp_gyr[i][j] = sum_gy_r;
            temp_gyg[i][j] = sum_gy_g;
            temp_gyb[i][j] = sum_gy_b;
        }
    }
    //Copy temp_gx and temp_gy into temp
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            tempr[i][j] = round(sqrt((temp_gyr[i][j]*temp_gyr[i][j]) + (temp_gxr[i][j]*temp_gxr[i][j])));
            tempg[i][j] = round(sqrt((temp_gyg[i][j]*temp_gyg[i][j]) + (temp_gxg[i][j]*temp_gxg[i][j])));
            tempb[i][j] = round(sqrt((temp_gyb[i][j]*temp_gyb[i][j]) + (temp_gxb[i][j]*temp_gxb[i][j])));

            if (tempr[i][j] > 255)
            {
                tempr[i][j] = 255;
            }
            if (tempg[i][j] > 255)
            {
                tempg[i][j] = 255;
            }
            if (tempb[i][j] > 255)
            {
                tempb[i][j] = 255;
            }

            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = tempr[i][j];
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = tempg[i][j];
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = tempb[i][j];
        }

    }
    // copy temp into image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //copy all temp image RGB into original RGB
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        }
    }


    return;
}
```

Comment: Aside: it's a mistake when *any* colour component is `> 255` to clamp *all* of them to `255`. Test them individually and limit each component separately.

Comment: ... but none of them such as `temp[i][j].rgbtRed > 255` *can* be, because you already assigned the computation to an 8-bit value. Make the check before you do that by assigning the rounded value to a temporary `int`, check the range, and then into the colour component.

Comment: thanks for pointing out.
But I am having a segmentation error now.
I have added a `temp_gxr[i][j]` variable to store the `sum_gx_r` and `temp_gyr[i][j]` variable to store the `sum_gy_r` 
then `tempr[i][j] = round(sqrt((temp_gyr[i][j]*temp_gyr[i][j]) + (temp_gxr[i][j]*temp_gxr[i][j])));`
and do the >255 colour individually.
Finally `temp[i][j].rgbtRed = tempr[i][j];`

Comment: I have not followed the whole code, but I don't see why that correction should cause a fault. *Is definitely not ideal. It is too lengthy.* Most people don't need *three* temporary images.

Comment: I have updated the code in the original question. It will be great if you can have a look again. Yeah it is definitely make the code very very lengthy.

Comment: Please don't update the code. We can't deal with interactive "moving targets" here - it is not a "dynamic tutorial" situation. Make any corrections, analyse, and post a new question.

Comment: You are creating *ten* integer arrays the size of the image on the stack. This alone can cause a segfault.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by 10 integer arrays? Where did I create that? thanks for your advice

Comment: tempr tempg tempb and all the others